# Setting up JNA in Gradle Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management, jna

I try to import a custom .dll inside my Gradle project. I add the dependencie inside build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '5.6.0'
}
```

but when I try to run the gradle build I receive this error

```
..java:170: error: cannot find symbol
                CustomLibrary INSTANCE = (CustomLibrary) Native.load("xxx", CustomLibrary.class);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   method load()
  location: class Native
1 error
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a transitive dependency on an older version of JNA in another dependency.

As you have tagged this with `spring boot` that is the likely cause.  Older Spring Boot versions used a 4.x (I think 4.3) JNA dependency and the syntax has changed.

The POM for Spring Boot uses a property `jna.version` that you could override if you were using Maven, but I don't think that is (easily) possible using Gradle.  However, updating to the latest version of Spring Boot should solve your problem.